Converting pandas-based function to pyspark udf for multithreading purposes
I want to use PySpark to compute a function f for different configurations. The function takes a Pandas DataFrame and a configuration in the form of a dictionary, and it returns three DataFrames. Below is a mock version of the function just for testing purposes:
import pandas as pd

def mock_fun(df: pd.DataFrame, config: dict):
    df['config'] = config
    return df, df, df

configs = [{'test': 1}, {'test': 2}]

Requirements:

Input: A Pandas DataFrame and a configuration dictionary.
Output: Three Pandas DataFrames.
Environment: I have AWS resources with PySpark, which I can take advantage of, and this is preferred over standard multithreading.

What I Have Tried:
I understand that PySpark's UDFs usually take columns as input, and I cannot overcome it. Below is my attempt to convert the three pandas data frames to json (which I can later reconvert).
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test_pandas_udf").getOrCreate()

# Define the UDF using pandas_udf
@pandas_udf(StructType([
    StructField("df1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("df2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("df3", StringType(), True)
]), functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def mock_udf(data: pd.DataFrame, config: dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df1, df2, df3 = mock_fun(data, config)
    return pd.DataFrame({
        "df1": [df1.to_json()],
        "df2": [df2.to_json()],
        "df3": [df3.to_json()]
    })

# Example DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': [1, 2, 3],
    'column2': [4, 5, 6]
})

# Convert to Spark DataFrame
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# Example configurations
configs = [{'test': 1}, {'test': 2}]

# Broadcast the configurations
broadcast_configs = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(configs)

# Apply the UDF
result_df = spark_df.withColumn("result", mock_udf(spark_df, broadcast_configs.value))

result_df.show(truncate=False)

Issues & Questions:
1.  UDF Signature: How to correctly define the UDF to take both the DataFrame and the configuration dictionary.
2.  How can I efficiently apply this UDF to multiple configurations using PySpark?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

The configs are complicated and the function is complex (albeit not impossible) to translate to pyspark.
